# I want to create a custom field on stripe checkout page and autopopulate that particular field

Tags: stripe-payments

am trying to create a custom field on stripe and autopopulate that field when a clients selects a plan e.g I want to add a credit field (numeric) to stripe checkout page and I also want the credit field to be automatically autopopulated without the customer having to input it manually.

Am using Gohighlevel which is a no code platform making it difficult for me to setup.

I need your help, thanks.

I wanted to link the database of the dynamic calculator that contained the credit values to stripe checkout page but it didn't work